# style.display as function is not hiding elements

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic main.js file I and want to hide and show some elements based on some conditions.
The problem is that when I launch the index.html the elements are not hiding properly.

Can anyone help me please?

`

```
init = async () => {
    hideElement(userInfo);
    window.web3 = await Moralis.Web3.enable();
    initUser();
}

initUser = async () => {
    if(await Moralis.User.current()){
        hideElement(userConnectButton);
        showElement(userProfiletButton);
    }else{
        showElement(userConnectButton);
        hideElement(userProfiletButton);
    }
}

login = async () => {
    try {
        await Moralis.Web3.authenticate();
        initUser();
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error)
    }
}

logout = async () => {
    await Moralis.User.logOut();
    hideElement(userInfo);
    initUser();
}

openUserInfo = async () => {
    user = await Moralis.User.current();
    if (user){
        showElement(userInfo);
    }else{
        login();
    }
}

hideElement = (element) => element.style.display = "none";
showElement = (element) => element.style.display = "block";
const userConnectButton = document.getElementById("btnConnect");
userConnectButton.onclick = login;

const userProfiletButton = document.getElementById("btnUserInfo");
userProfileButton.onclick = openUserInfo;

const userInfo = document.getElementById("userInfo");
document.getElementById("btnCloseUserInfo").onclick = () => hideElement(userInfo);
document.getElementById("btbLogOut").onclick = () => hideElement(logOut);
```

`

Comment: please show the code of your index.html file

Comment: You aren't calling `init`.

Comment: Hi I wasn't able to post the full code so I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70439046/javascript-hideelement-function-does-not-work